# What is Native Driver?? how it is different from ODBC driver

Tags: java, performance, drivers

What is Native Driver, how will the performance be increased with the help of native drivers, - we are trying to connect from tableau to cloudera impala.
presently we are using ODBC drivers for connection.

Comment: Many BI tools *(e.g. Oracle Data Integrator, Oracle BI, IBM WebStuff, Microstrategy, etc.)* ship with so-called "native drivers" that are actually **DataDirect** ODBC or JDBC drivers, bundled with an OEM license. Maybe Tableau does the same.

Comment: From personal experience, the DataDirect driver for Impala works exactly like the Cloudera Impala driver... except when it does not work *(i.e. no support for SSL, no support for Kerberos through a Load Balancer, etc.)*

Answer (score 0):

**Native drivers** are Informatica's recommended data access method, when available for your Informatica platform

The **ODBC driver**  (Open Database Conectivity) is database-specific, i.e. a Microsoft Access ODBC driver will only talk to a Microsoft Access database. The ODBC Driver Manager is the interface between Informatica and the ODBC driver